# Do witches attend Durmstrang?

Tags: harry-potter

In the films, we only see male students from Durmstrang. Do we know if witches also attend that school?  If not, where do *they* go to school?

Comment: Only in the films are Durmstrang and Beauxbatons single gendered schools.

Comment: @CandiedMango I remember in the books that there were males in Beauxbatons but I thought I remembered Malfoy saying his father had considered sending him there with one of the reasons being it was a male only school

Comment: I had to answer because you made me doubt myself! Also It was founded by a witch :)

Comment: @CandiedMango evidently it's been far too long since I've read the books!

Comment: I'm waiting til I get the illustrated PS to start again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, Durmstrang is a mixed school.**

One girl is mentioned in the books. When Harry lets some Durmstrang students through the doors, we have mention of an unnamed girl as part of their party:

> Karkaroff turned and led his students toward the doors, reaching them at exactly the same moment as Harry, Ron, and Hermione. Harry stopped to let him walk through first.
>
> “Thank you,” said Karkaroff carelessly, glancing at him. […]
>
> Out of the corner of his eye, Harry saw comprehension dawn on a few of their faces. **The boy with food all down his front nudged the girl next to him and pointed openly at Harry’s forehead.**
>
> — *Goblet of Fire*, chapter 16 (*The Goblet of Fire*)

Very few of the Durmstrang students in the book are given an explicit gender. Krum is male, and there are one or two other named boys; otherwise they are mostly described as “students”. The gendering of Beauxbatons and Durmstrang was an addition in the films.

The [Pottermore entry](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/durmstrang-institute) also includes several hints that Durmstrang would accept witches. The opening paragraph describes it thusly:

> It is true that Durmstrang, which has turned out many truly **great witches and wizards**, has twice in its history fallen under the stewardship of wizards of dubious allegiance or nefarious intent, and that it has one infamous ex-pupil.

It’s also worth noting that Durmstrang was actually founded by a witch:

> The first of these unhappy men, Harfang Munter, took over the school shortly after the mysterious death of its founder, the great Bulgarian witch Nerida Vulchanova.

While not conclusive, it would be surprising if she forbade witches from attending her school.

---

And while I’m crushing the movie’s idea that Beauxbatons and Durmstang are both single-sex schools, here’s a quote from the arrival that shows that Beauxbatons is also mixed-sex:

> Harry, whose attention had been focused completely upon Madame Maxime, now noticed that about a dozen boys and girls, all, by the look of them, in their late teens, had emerged from the carriage and were now standing behind Madame Maxime.
>
> — *Goblet of Fire*, chapter 15 (*Beauxbatons and Durmstrang*)

Comment: Can't believe you didn't notice all the duplicates :)

Comment: @DVK Gah, must have had a brain fart while searching. Oh well, thanks for spotting. :)

Answer (score 5):

> It is true that Durmstrang, which has turned out many **truly great witches** and wizards, has twice in its history fallen under the stewardship of wizards of dubious allegiance or nefarious intent, and that it has one infamous ex-pupil.
>   
>  [Pottermore - Durmstrang Institute](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/durmstrang-institute)